# if-block in fields_for is rendering HTML-escaped hidden fields

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, haml

This is a Rails 3 application with HAML.
I have the following:

```
= f.fields_for :bar_memberships do |bar_membership_fields|
  = 'FIELD'
```

I have encapsulated the problem. This code prints:
FIELD 
FIELD
FIELD
as expected.

But the following code:

```
= f.fields_for :bar_memberships do |bar_membership_fields|
  - if bar_membership_fields.object.new_record?
    = 'FIELD'
```

Renders a lot of HTML-escaped hidden inputs in the source code, and displays them on the page!

```
'<input id="person_bar_memberships_attributes_0_id" name="person[bar_memberships_attributes][0][id]" type="hidden" value="824" />
<input id="person_bar_memberships_attributes_1_id" name="person[bar_memberships_attributes][1][id]" type="hidden" value="825" />'
FIELD
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the following code:

```
= f.fields_for :bar_memberships do |bar_membership_fields|
  - if bar_membership_fields.object.new_record?
    = 'FIELD'
```

By doing:

```
= f.fields_for :bar_memberships do |bar_membership_fields|
  = ""
  - if bar_membership_fields.object.new_record?
    = 'FIELD'
```

If anyone knows why please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You must return something other than `nil` in the `fields_for` block.

[This issue has been fixed in Haml 4.0.4 by mattwildig](https://github.com/haml/haml/issues/439):

> The `#fields_for` helper generates a hidden input field for each record, which it adds to the result of capturing the block. Normally the return value of `capture` will be a `SafeBuffer`, so this won’t be escaped. However if the block doesn’t write anything to the buffer then Haml returns a literal empty `String` from `capture`. The hidden input element is concatted to this string, and when it is combined with the rest of the entries, since it is a `String` being added to a `SafeBuffer`, it gets escaped.